# How to download Ruby (<2.0) on virtualbox/ubunto 20.04 using rbenv

Tags: ruby, linux, ssl

I am having issues installing Ruby with rbenv and it appears to be an openssl issue. I have followed the below links with no success

Links:
[OpenSSL error installing Ruby 2.1.x and 2.3.x on Archlinux with ruby-install/ruby-build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116005/openssl-error-installing-ruby-2-1-x-and-2-3-x-on-archlinux-with-ruby-install-rub)

https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/wiki#openssl-sslv3_method-undeclared-error

Ubuntu 20.04
OpenSSL 1.0.2
ruby-build 20211019

---

```
scoop@scoop-VirtualBox:~$ rbenv install 1.9.3-p327

Downloading yaml-0.1.6.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/7da6971b4bd08a986dd2a61353bc422362bd0edcc67d7ebaac68c95f74182749
Installing yaml-0.1.6...
Installed yaml-0.1.6 to /home/scoop/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327

Downloading ruby-1.9.3-p327.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p327.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-1.9.3-p327...

WARNING: ruby-1.9.3-p327 is past its end of life and is now unsupported.
It no longer receives bug fixes or critical security updates.


BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 20.04 using ruby-build 20211019)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20211022151319.51817.ZFwydR
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20211022151319.51817.log

Last 10 log lines:
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
ossl_ocsp.c: In function ‘ossl_ocspcid_get_serial’:

ossl_ocsp.c:694:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  694 | }
      | ^

make[2]: *** [Makefile:267: ossl_ocsp.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20211022151319.51817.ZFwydR/ruby-1.9.3-p327/ext/openssl'

make[1]: *** [exts.mk:126: ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20211022151319.51817.ZFwydR/ruby-1.9.3-p327'
make: *** [uncommon.mk:178: build-ext] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I found Ubuntu > 18.04 does not have the correct dependencies to support OpenSSL 1.0 so I switched to 18.04 and did the following:

```
# cd into source directory you downloaded and unarchived
./config --prefix=/opt/openssl-1.0 shared
make
make test
sudo make install
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=/opt/openssl-1.0" rbenv install <version>
```

this comes from the below link:
https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/wiki#openssl-sslv3_method-undeclared-error